# TypeError: builder.LuisRecognizer is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I tried to use the LuisRecognizer as stated in the documentation for getting the suitable intent.
Initialized the builder with:

```
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var luis = new builder.LuisRecognizer(luisRequest);
var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({intentThreshold:thresholds["luis"], recognizers: luis}); 
console.log(intents)
```

But I get back:

```
TypeError: builder.LuisRecognizer is not a constructor
```

Did I overlook something? The documentation seems up to date.
`luisRequest` is correct, I already checked.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The parameter should be the URL from `luis.ai > Manage > Azure Resources`, represented by a string:

```
const luisrecognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(process.env.LUIS_MODEL_URL);
```

Comment: It already is the correct string. I just found out that `LuisRecognizer` is now from another module called ` botbuilder-ai`. They changed it in the latest version. Oh man :D